# Why does compiler gives me error unusued variable n?

Tags: c, scope, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
        printf("Welcome to blabla\n");


// This next part gets user input and checks if the integer given by user is between 1 and 8

        int n;
        do
        {
            printf("Give me a integer between 1 and 8.\n");
            int n = GetInt();
        }
        while (n >= 1 && n <= 8);

        printf("You picked the number %d.\n", n);   

        return(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't use the inner n.

Comment: The concept is called scope

Comment: you should add `-Wshadow` or equivalent warning flags to your compiler call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
int n = GetInt();
```

tries to declare a *new* local variable `n`. It's completely separate from the local variable you declared earlier:

```
int n;
```

When you call `GetInt()`, you just want to assign the value to the *existing* variable, like this:

```
n = GetInt();
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
int n = GetInt();
```

with

```
n = GetInt();
```

You were introducing a second variable `n` with block scope that was going to be discarded after the first `}`. The lifetime of an automatic object ends at the end of the block where it has been declared.

Comment: That answers how to fix it, but doesn't give any indication of why it was wrong to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You're redeclaring `n` inside the loop, so the outside declaration is not used.  It's probably not what you want.

Replace

```
int n = GetInt();
```

with:

```
n = GetInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring n as int n once again inside the do {} ? just change it to :

```
n = GetInt();
```

The scope of inner n is till the '}' of do. After that it was never used. The n outside the loop is the used n